# Selecting distinct counts from nested subqueries

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to get pagination working with a query that has a left join. This is causing my count to be the number of rows, not the number of products. To paraphrase my query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by tmp.prodId, tmp.prodYear) as rnum, 
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS totalRecords,
  tmp.* 
FROM (
  SELECT
    product.*, widget.* 
  FROM A_PROD product
  LEFT JOIN A_WID widget
    ON product.prodId = widget.prodId
    AND product.prodYear = widget.prodYear
  ORDER BY product.prodId ASC ) tmp
)
WHERE rnum BETWEEN 1 and 10
```

This is resulting in

```
|rnum|totalRecords|prodId|prodYear|widgetId|
| 1  |     3      | 13   |  2013  |  xyz   |
| 1  |     3      | 13   |  2013  |  abc   |
| 1  |     3      | 13   |  2013  |  mno   |
```

when what I am looking for is

```
|rnum|totalRecords|prodId|prodYear|widgetId|
| 1  |     1      | 13   |  2013  |  xyz   |
| 1  |     1      | 13   |  2013  |  abc   |
| 1  |     1      | 13   |  2013  |  mno   |
```

That way the orm will treat them as the same product with different widgets, the pagination will treat it as only one row in the output and the 'Displaying X products out of Y' message will be correct.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the prodid (or is that prodid/year pairs) in the output.  If so, move the logic to the outer query, so the `where` affects it.  This might work:

```
SELECT count(distinct prodid) over () as totalRecords, t.*
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by tmp.prodId, tmp.prodYear) as rnum, 
             tmp.* 
      FROM (SELECT product.*, widget.* 
            FROM A_PROD product LEFT JOIN
                 A_WID widget
                 ON product.prodId = widget.prodId AND product.prodYear = widget.prodYear
          ) tmp
    ) t
WHERE rnum BETWEEN 1 and 10
order by prodId ASC;
```

Note:  I don't think the `order by` in the subquery has an effect.  I moved it to the outer query.

And, I don't know if DB2 supports `count(distinct)` as a window/analytic function.  If not, there is a workaround.

EDIT:

With no distinct in `count`, you can sum the values where the row number returns 1:

```
SELECT sum(case when rnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over () as totalprodyear, t.*
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by tmp.prodId, tmp.prodYear) as rnum, 
             tmp.* 
      FROM (SELECT product.*, widget.* 
            FROM A_PROD product LEFT JOIN
                 A_WID widget
                 ON product.prodId = widget.prodId AND product.prodYear = widget.prodYear
          ) tmp
    ) t
WHERE rnum BETWEEN 1 and 10
order by prodId ASC;
```

That counts `prodyear`.  If you want just `prod`, add another `row_number()` partitioning only on `prodid`.

Comment: I am afraid you are right about no distinct in count. I definatly see the logic here though

Comment: @Gordon Once again.. I wish I could be like you, in writing SQLs !! _Genius_ --Maheswaran Ravisankar

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I am doing this wrong but using count+case is resulting in the same number as count *. Using Sum+case (which may have been your intent) results in getting a totalprodyear of 1

Comment: @BobRoberts . . . That should have been `sum()`, not `count()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, that is always spitting out 1 as rnum is only 1 once.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Gordon Linoff's answer to work but it did give me an idea.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT MAX(rnum) OVER () as totalprodyear, t.*
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by tmp.prodId, tmp.prodYear) as rnum, 
             tmp.* 
      FROM (SELECT product.*, widget.* 
            FROM A_PROD product LEFT JOIN
                 A_WID widget
                 ON product.prodId = widget.prodId AND product.prodYear = widget.prodYear
          ) tmp
    ) t
)
WHERE rnum BETWEEN 1 and 10
order by prodId ASC;
```

Did work for my purposes